# WAMPSERVER GD2 - doesn't support jpeg images?

Tags: php

I have WAMPSERVER 2.0 installed on my localhost with php_gd2 extension enabled, however when I'm trying to save a jpeg image I get this exception:

```
Your GD installation does not support JPG image types
```

How to enable JPG images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the comments made by other developers on the PHP manual.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#74891

and

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#70832

it is something to do with libjpeg